# Hash::check() returning false in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have used Hash::check() number of times for password updating function. It was working fine. But here it always returns false. I don't understand why its returning false. Here is the code that worked for me.

```
$pass_data = array(
            'current_pass' => $post['old_pass'],
            'new_pass' => $post['new_pass'],
            );
$pass_data['new_pass'] = bcrypt($pass_data['new_pass']);

    if (\Hash::check($pass_data['current_pass'],\Auth::user()->password )) 
            {

            $user = new User();
             if($user->where('id',\Auth::user()->id)->update(['password'=>$pass_data['new_pass']])){
                    return response()->json(['msg'=>'Password Changed']);
                }
            }

             else{
                return response()->json(['msg'=>'Wrong Password']);
            }
```

Here is the code which is returning false, Here the $mem_id is not the Authenticated user(is it because of changing non authenticated user's pass ?).

```
    $mem_id = $request['mem_id'];
    $old_pass = $request['mem_old_pass'];
    $mem_pass = User::where('id',$mem_id)->pluck('password');


    if (\Hash::check($old_pass,$mem_pass )) {

        $new_pass = bcrypt($request['mem_new_pass']);

        $update = User::where('id',$mem_id)->update(['name'=>$request['mem_name'],'email'=>$request['mem_email'],'password'=>$new_pass]);


        if ($update) {

            $updated_user = User::where('id',$mem_id)->get();
            return response()->json(['msg'=>'updated','user'=>$updated_user]);
        }
        else{

            return response()->json(['msg'=>'update_failed']);
        }
    }

    else{
        return response()->json(['msg'=>'pass_fail']);
    }
```

I am getting the response **'pass_fail'**.

Answer (score 1):

Because the pluck method doesn't return the specified column value.

Answer (score 0):

[Usage.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/hashing)

```
if (Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedPassword)) {
    // The passwords match...
}
```

You are passing to `Hash::check` not a plain text password but a result of `bcrypt($old_pass);`. You should pass plain text, not encrypted.

Comment: Yep, he does crypting right. I'm talking about second part of code concerning checking.

Comment: edited the question , that one was a mistake, I am passing the plain text only. Still i get the error

Comment: see if i use `\Auth::user()->password` instead of $mem_pass in hash check it is working fine. But if i use pluck the password. The issue occurs

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with pluck(). when i used this code, it was working perfectly

```
$member = User::find($mem_id);
$mem_pass = $member->password;
```

Now I passed $mem_pass to Hash::check , it worked perfectly